# Dimension of moduli stack and moduli space of sheaves on surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Let $M(r;c_1, c_2)$ be the moduli space of $S$ equivalence class of slope semistable (w.r.to $H$), rank $r$ torsion free sheaves with Chern invariants $c_1,c_2$ on $X$ and $\mathcal M(r;c_1, c_2)$ be the moduli stack of slope semistable (w.r.to $H$), rank $r$ torsion free sheaves with Chern invariants $c_1,c_2$ on $X$.

Assume that, all the sheaves in moduli space are slope stable  (w.r.to $H$) and the moduli space is smooth and has expected dimension. Then my question is that is there a precise relation between the dimensions of the moduli stack and the moduli space? are they same or the dimension of the stack is $1$ less than the dimension of the moduli space?

Any suggestion, remark and reference is welcome

Comment: It is a matter of convention.  There is an Artin stack of all flat families of coherent sheaves.  The open substack that parameterizes stable sheaves is a $\mathbb{G}_m$ gerbe over the coarse moduli space.  In that sense, the dimension of the stack is one less than the dimension of the coarse moduli space.

Comment: @Jason Starr, thank you very much for the answer. Could you please direct me to a source in the literature which discusses (or at least mentions) this.